# missing argument in codeigniter with variables

Tags: php, codeigniter

I was passing my arguments correctly by URL and then I don't know what's wrong with the variables

> Message: Missing argument 1 for Welcome::index()
>
> Filename: controllers/Welcome.php
>
> Line Number: 10
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /var/www/html/proyecto/application/controllers/Welcome.php Line:
>   10 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: /var/www/html/proyecto/index.php Line: 292 Function:
>   require_once

Controller:

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('login_model');
    }

    public function index($password){

        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('index');
    }

}
```

Comment: May be in routes you need to configure something like `$route['welcome/(:any)'] = 'welcome/index/$1';` http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: And then try `index($password = NULL)` or something because $password I think would be a uri segment. `http://localhost/index.php/welcome/1234`

Comment: why if I add password = null works and if I dont add NULL not works?

Comment: Aron, if you add password = null you're setting the default value for the variable. So if you don't add it as a parameter on the function call, there won't be problem because there is already a value to it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the pariable to view page? Then use this code

```
 class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
        function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('login_model');
        }



 //value of password fetch to the variable $password
    //eg:$password='123';




 public function index($password){

            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('index',$password);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your controller need to accept one argument

```
public function index(**$password**)
```

so you need to define what `$password` coming from.

or you just edit your controller

```
public function index($password = "")
```

to avoid the warning.

Answer (score 0):

```
 class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

        function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('login_model');
        }


public function index($password = "") {

            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('index',$password);
        }

}
```

Thanks angel and weirdo

Comment: But you just used their answers as your own this makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

You should check your requested url. You may see the [reference here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html) in the "Passing URI Segments to your Functions" section.

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct(){
       parent::__construct();
       $this->load->model('login_model');
    }

    public function index($password){

       $this->load->view('header');
       $this->load->view('index');
    }
}
```

From your code  above, you create a required $password variable for each request. So you must put a value in the end of your url for the password.
i.e. example.com/index.php/Welcome/index/password

I hope this help. thank you.